# rescue 'nil cant be coerced into float' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a way to rescue such an error. I am going through some legacy projects and it appears line three in the below method is causing the system to crash with this error `nil can't be coerced into Float`

```
  def apply_discount_if_positive(price)
    if price > 0.0
   (price - (price * base_client_discount)).round(2)
    else
      price
    end
  end
```

the thing I don't understand though, is this.

I know this isn't an ideal solution but even if I add `price.to_f` before the condition statement it still doesn't work.

Comment: if the error is in line 3, it's gotta be that `base_client_discount` is nil, so provide a fallback for that. (otherwise it would fail in line 2 upon comparing price with 0.0)

Comment: Yeah @MarianTheisen, you were right. I did just add .to_f on the end of that and it fixed the error. Don't know if its the most ideal solution but hey ho

Answer (score 0):

I would simply check if the discount is not nil before doing line 3, smth like this should work:

```
def apply_discount_if_positive(price)
    if price > 0.0 && base_client_discount
     (price - (price * base_client_discount)).round(2)
    else
      price
    end
end
```